# Rubygems do not install on OS X Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I used to have no problems at all with ruby, gems and all related stuff. But after installing X Code Developer Tools and upgrading to Lion the gems do not install.

I get the following error for every gem. This is the message for sqlite as an example:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

What went wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 75):

I had to install the Command Line Tools in the latest Xcode-Version (4.3.1) and

```
sudo gem install rails
```

worked like a charm.

To install Command Line Tools, go to Xcode Preferences > Downloads or use the following command in terminal (thx @[Purell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128508/purrell)):

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Yep. To install Command Line Tools, go to XCode Preferences > Downloads.

Comment: So apparently if you have OSX 10.9 Mavericks and Xcode 5.0, commandline tools doesn't (always?) show up in Preferences-->Downloads. But you can install it with "xcode-select --install"

Answer (score 16):

I'm using Mavericks and Ruby 2.0.0 and I also got this error (mkmf.rb can't find header files) when installing gems. I solved this issue by creating some symbolic links in Terminal.

```
#First install developer tools again:
xcode-select --install

#Create symbolic link to Ruby include (updated for 10.9)
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include

#Create symbolic link to config.h (updated for 10.9)
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/Headers/ruby/config.h /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/config.h
```

Comment: Upgrading to Mavericks seemed to have uninstalled developer tools. Running the first command from David fixes this issue for me. No need to symlink.

Answer (score 12):

*I faced same problem while trying to install rails on my Lion. This is how i could solve it.*

Install rvm

`$ curl https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable`

Install osx-gcc-installer

https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Installed new version of ruby

`rvm install 1.9.3`

Typed to following command to show the requirements

`rvm requirements`

To use an RVM installed Ruby as default, instead of the system ruby:

`rvm system ; rvm gemset export system.gems ; rvm 1.9.3 ; rvm gemset import system.gems # migrate your gems
    rvm alias create default 1.9.3`

Installed rails:

`sudo gem install rails`

My Mac is now read for rails!! YAY!!

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct solution to your problem, but I'd suggest using [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) to install fresh rubies and gems. That should take care of it.

Answer (score 4):

While installing Rails I had the error :

> can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

As i had already Xcode installed, I had just to install Command Line Tools to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to have XCode installed, it includes ruby.h as well as some other important files needed to compile other native gems.

Comment: Welcom to SO. If i read the OP's question correct, he stateds he has XCode installed.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i'm sorry i can't test this answer but i would suggest to change the default search paths in your bashrc and extconf.rb since the Library files seem to be moved in Lion.

(P.S. if he wants to work with the default 1.8 Version, rvm would be an unneeded hassle)

Comment: You open up a Terminalwindow, choose your favorite Editor, and edit your .bashrc (usually in the path /Users/<Your Username>/.bashrc)

Comment: I know how to do that. I just do not know which path I should add there.

Comment: Oh sorry i misunderstood:
I'd suggest: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest version of xcode, that fixed the problem for me. Make sure xcodebuild is in your path.

running xcodebuild -version in a terminal window should output 4.2.1 (4.x at least).

Answer (score 0):

After a OS-Update make sure that you do accept the X-Code license even when you have used command-line-tools before. Only then some header-files will be available. To accept the license you have to run X-Code once.

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to run it with the `sudo` command.

`sudo gem install sqlite3`

not:

`gem install sqlite3`