# Failed to build gem native extension: Unable to install Rails + MySQL2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am on MAC OS X LION and keep getting error message Failed to build gem native extension when trying to install rails and mysql.

This is what I am doing. I enter:

```
    $ sudo gem install rails
```

**Error message**

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.6.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.6.5/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
ingjerd$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

**The same happens when I try to install mysql2 gem.**

When I do the command

```
    gem list
```

Then rails and mysql is not in that list of local gems.

When I try the command

```
    which rails
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/rails
```

So then that kind of makes me think that rails is in there somewhere. But when I try:

```
  $ rails -v
```

I get:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
$ sudo gem install rails You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

**I wonder whether this happens because I did things in the wrong order?**

I first updated gems and then I installed XCODE and changed the .bash_profile to the following - and I think I should have done this before updating gems.

```
PS1="\u$ "
alias ll="ls -laGH"

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

I think I should have done the .bash_profile path before updating gems and I should also have installed xcode first, but I was unsure of the order of doing things.

Please help a true newbie to ruby as I can't start learning before I have a working environment....

Comment: Here are a couple of posts that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454361/rubygems-do-not-install-on-os-x-lion --and-- http://nearthespeedoflight.com/article/how_to_fix__mkmf.rb_can_t_find_header_files_for_ruby__on_mac_os_x_lion

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you have `rails` in  `/usr/bin/rails` after installing it with gem. You should find the correct executable in `GEM_PATH/rails-.../bin`.

Comment: Yes, and the core problem is that you're missing ruby headers. What ruby package/bundle did you install?

Comment: focus on getting ruby installed and able to return `ruby -v`.  If you can, aim for 1.9.2+ over the 1.8 series, it's very stable at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try out a few of these things or potentially try setting it up from scratch on a different mac to see how that goes... I did not install ruby, ruby was in the system already (1.8.7). Will try to update to a newer version as well. Problem is that I am really new to using terminal, so kind of learning the commands at the same time. If anyone has a great tip on how to update ruby, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, installing Xcode and then Command Line Tools worked.

You can install Command Line Tools from Xcode Preferences > Downloads > Command Line Tools. I don't know if you can just download Command Line Tools from [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) and skip the Xcode installation.

I also recommend you to install [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)– see that you can install it with `brew`, mentioned below– to manage several ruby versions, or if you want [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)– I have tried both of them, don't know exactly what are its differences. This is because when you upgrade ruby, PATH system variable needs to be changed to detect newly installed Ruby `which -a ruby`shows you the paths of the Rubies you have installed.

The second part, to install mysql2, I have installed [brew](https://brew.sh/) and then mysql with its header files.

```
# to install brew
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
# to install mysql
brew install mysql
```