# ruby bcrypt install error on OSX

Tags: ruby, bcrypt

I tried to execute 'sudo gem install bcrypt-ruby'

And got the following error:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error installing bcrypt-ruby:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>   mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out

I'm running osx lion with ruby 1.8.7 and xcode 4.5.2

(Thanks for helping me)

Comment: Have you [installed the XCode command line tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454361/rubygems-do-not-install-on-os-x-lion)?

Comment: Have you looked in this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119153/why-do-i-get-a-bcrypt-ruby-gem-install-error